# What does n=n( ) mean in R?

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

The other day I was reading the following lines in R and I don't understand what the `%>%` and `summarise(n=n())` and `summarise(total=n())` meant. I understand the `group_by` and `ungroup` methods though.

Can someone help out? There isn't any documentation for this either.

```
library(dplyr)
net.multiplicity <- group_by(net, nodeid, epoch) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>%
                    ungroup() %>% group_by(n) %>% summarise(total=n())
```

Comment: There is documentation for `n()`. Type `?n()` in console. It is basically the number of observations within a group

Comment: `%>%` is a newish form of syntax to allow pipes and, loosely, makes code readable/writable from left-to-right.  See [this summary](http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/) for more details.

Comment: Threre is also documentation for `%>%`. Type `?"%>%"` (you need the quotes because of the special characters)

Comment: If you are going to do `?n()` or `?"%>%"` make sure you have `dplyr` loaded first i.e. `library(dplyr)` or it won't work.

Answer (score 17):

This is from the `dplyr` package. `n=n()` means that a variable named `n` will be assigned the number of rows (think number of observations) in the summarized data.

the `%>%` is read as "and then" and is way of listing your functions sequentially rather then nesting them. So that command is saying you should do the grouping and then `summarize` the result of the grouping by the number of rows in each group and then `ungroup` that result, and then group the un-grouped data based on `n` and then `summarize` that by the total number of rows in each of the new groups.

Comment: Would we even need to ungroup? We could just group the grouped data based on n instead of grouping ungrouped data, couldn't we?

Comment: @Glassjawed I think you are correct. You can use an additional argument `add` that by default is `FALSE`, but when `TRUE` it adds to the exiting groups rather than overriding them.